# Rollback date specific changes for user

Tags: sql, oracle, transactions

I have updated a few changes some time ago using the commit statement. I now need to roll back the changes. These changes were done using my Oracle user account.

Comment: If you commit changes, they are commited. Probably, you want to restore a backup to roll back these changes

Answer (score 2):

You could use flashback. Here's an example:

Sample data:

```
SQL> create table test (id number, name varchar2(20));

Table created.

SQL> insert into test
  2    select 1, 'Littlefoot' from dual union all
  3    select 2, 'Scott'      from dual union all
  4    select 3, 'Tiger'      from dual;

3 rows created.
```

Set date(time) format so that we'd see what's going on:

```
SQL> alter session set nls_date_format = 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24.mi:ss';

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-------------------
05.12.2019 13.56:38
```

Let's update a row and commit changes:

```
SQL> update test set name = 'Bigfoot' where id = 1;

1 row updated.

SQL> commit;

Commit complete.

SQL> select sysdate from dual;

SYSDATE
-------------------
05.12.2019 13.57:05
```

Selecting from table shows new data:

```
SQL> select * From test;

                   ID NAME
--------------------- --------------------
                    1 Bigfoot
                    2 Scott
                    3 Tiger

SQL>
```

But, using flashback, we can see into the past:

```
SQL> select * from test as of timestamp to_timestamp('05.12.2019 13:57:00', 'dd.mm.yyyy hh24:mi:ss');

                   ID NAME
--------------------- --------------------
                    1 Littlefoot
                    2 Scott
                    3 Tiger
```

See if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not have the `update` statement, then you might want to use a backup to load a previous state of the database. If you have an update, which looks like

```
update mytable
set column1 = 'somevalue'
where column2 = 'someothervalue';
```

then you need to analyze your `update`. Run

```
select *
from mytable
where column2 = 'someothervalue' or column1 = 'somevalue';
```

This way you will be able to see what the actual values are. If `column1` and `column2` are the same, then you will want `column1` to be switched back for the updated rows and to not switch back for the rows which you didn't `update`.

Anyway, in order to set the values back to their previous state you will need contextual information about your data. If this answer does not lead you to the solution, then you will need to describe what your `update` looks like and what data might have been affected.